# Get Unique contents from Ruby Hash

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, hash

I have a Hash @estate:

```
    [#<Estate id: 1, Name: "Thane ", Address: "Thane St.", created_at: "2013-06-21 16:40:50", updated_at: "2013-06-21 16:40:50", user_id: 2, asset_file_name: "DSC02358.JPG", asset_content_type: "image/jpeg", asset_file_size: 5520613, asset_updated_at: "2013-06-21 16:40:49", Mgmt: "abc">,
    #<Estate id: 2, Name: "Mumbai", Address: "Mumbai St.", created_at: "2013-06-21 19:13:59", updated_at: "2013-06-21 19:14:28", user_id: 2, asset_file_name: "DSC02359.JPG", asset_content_type: "image/jpeg", asset_file_size: 5085580, asset_updated_at: "2013-06-21 19:13:57", Mgmt: "abc">]
```

Is it possible to make new Hash with unique values according to the `user_id: 2`, because currently 2 elements have the user_id same i.e 2, I just want it once in the hash, what should I do ?

Comment: I see estate id and user id as being two, where is there a duplicate ?

Comment: Apparently, the output of @estate is an `Array` object, not a `Hash`.

Comment: OK I see two active instances for Estate, one has estate id 1, the other estate id 2. Each of them has `user_id` of 2. Exactly what is it you want to do with these? They are distinct Estate records with the same user id. "I just want it once in the hash" is not clear to me.

Comment: i just want the array to contain all the elements with unique user_id

Comment: Are the objects stored in your database, or are they coming from a different source? Fix the problem at the source, not midstream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be something like a `has_many` relation between `User` model and `Estate` model, right? If I understood you correctly, than you need in fact to group your `Estate` by `user_id`:

PostgreSQL:

```
 Estate.select('DISTINCT ON (user_id) *').all
```

MySQL:

```
 Estate.group(:user_id).all
```

P.S. I'd not recommend to select all records from a database and then process them with Ruby as databases handle operations with data in much more efficient way.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an sample example to get you a good start:

```
h = [ { a: 2, b: 3}, { a: 2, c: 3 } ]
h.uniq { |i| i[:a] }
# => [{:a=>2, :b=>3}]
```

Comment: its working perfectly fine in rails console, but when i am using it in the controller I dont know whats wrong, i also tried in the debug mode but it doesnt work